# Java String Comparison Unreliable

Tags: java, android, string, comparison, string-comparison

Have had this issue for a while now and have been unsure of the cause.

I am sending and receiving data from a device. All I want to do is compare the received message with a variable set on the object being sent.

For example, I can send an object which has a receivedValue of `'Received 86 C0'`.

If this sends successfully, I should get returned something like:

```
IRDA1: Received 86 C0
```

I logged below the returned value on the object under log name **'send'** and I then log what is returned under name **'test'**.

The below code shows how I compare the 2 strings:

```
public boolean checkReceived(DataCommand command) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (message.contains(command.getCommandReturn())) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now it just doesn't seem to work. It does work eventually but takes forever. For example the below log shows how many times it took for the program to finally compare the strings properly.

```
06-26 15:04:33.820 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:34.001 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:35.838 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:36.007 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:37.856 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:39.874 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:40.035 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: 1: Received 
06-26 15:04:41.891 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:42.054 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:43.971 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:44.133 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:45.991 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:46.221 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:48.009 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:50.024 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:50.191 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:52.041 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:54.060 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:54.221 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:56.078 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:56.239 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:58.097 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:04:58.271 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:00.112 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:02.131 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:02.305 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:04.147 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:06.165 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:06.326 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:08.183 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:08.346 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:10.201 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:10.361 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:12.220 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:12.392 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:14.236 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:14.429 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 8B FF
06-26 15:05:16.255 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:18.274 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:18.447 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:20.293 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:22.312 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:22.482 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:24.330 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:24.468 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Rece
06-26 15:05:26.352 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:26.518 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:28.371 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:28.543 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:30.388 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:32.408 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:32.577 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:34.425 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:36.444 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:36.588 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:38.464 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:38.611 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:40.482 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:40.642 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:42.500 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:44.518 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:46.537 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:48.555 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:50.574 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:52.593 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:52.756 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:54.612 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:54.790 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:56.630 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:56.791 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:05:58.649 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:00.667 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:00.829 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:02.685 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:04.703 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:04.868 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:06.720 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:06.900 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:08.739 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:10.760 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:12.778 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:12.951 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:14.962 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:16.980 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:17.149 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:18.999 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:19.142 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:21.018 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:23.029 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:25.043 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:27.062 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:27.219 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:29.081 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:29.247 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:31.099 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:31.277 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:33.111 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:33.299 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:35.130 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:37.148 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:39.166 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:39.309 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:41.186 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:41.365 24733-24733/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/test: IRDA1: Received 86 C0
06-26 15:06:43.204 24733-25852/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/send: Received 86 C0
```

FYI: `command.getCommandReturn()` is just getting that received variable i was talking about.

Thanks.

Update:

I should ave cleared that up my bad.

Message is string variable declared at the start of the class in the activity.

```
 public void onEventMainThread(TemplateMessageSystem event) {

        Log.i("test", event.getMessage());
        message = event.getMessage();
    }
```

This is a message receiver working on a different thread receiving incoming messages. It does set the message variable correctly and to what it should. I am unsure on the loading time for string comparison, but there is probably 2 strings every 1-2 seconds being received by this method.

Comment: Since message is not passed into this method, I'll assume it's mutable state in your object that is not synchronized properly.  String comparison is perfectly reliable, but writing multi-threaded code is hard even for smart people.

Comment: Updated to explain message

Comment: A global, mutable variable?  That's even worse.

Comment: Bad choice of words. I wouldn't say its global but declared at the start of the class in question.

Comment: @timburnt whether it is global or not, if it's being written in one thread and read on another, you need to ensure visibility of the value. Either surround the write/read with synchronized blocks, or make it `volatile`, or use an `AtomicReference<String>`.

Comment: So I have a getter and setter for the message. Should I consider volatility on this end, on the read side where I declare the variable at the top of the class, or both? Thanks.